# Calling Class Function with a Timer,

Tags: c#, events, timer

I have a Variable Class. Its holds information does gets updated too often for the user to see. So I want to use a Timer to update the GUI just every second or so. Here is the code:

```
   public Variable()
    {
        TimerInit();
        _value.timestamp = 0;
        _value.value = 0;

    }

    private void TimerInit()
    {

        _UpdateTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        // Set the Interval to 5 seconds.
        _UpdateTimer.Interval = 5000;
        _UpdateTimer.Enabled = true;
        _UpdateTimer.Stop();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.VariableChange.Invoke(this, new VariableChangeEventArgs() { value = Value }); // invoking the gui
    }
```

You can spot the Problem: this is in an static function. How am I supposed to get to my object? The given Source Object is no help because it is not holding the data. I cannot make the variable class static.

Every example and help I find is about calling the console. This cannot be that hard but even the documentation from MSDN is not helping.

Hope you can deconfuse me.

Thomas

Comment: Why does `OnTimedEvent` need to be static?

Comment: Just remove static keyword from the event hendler declaration!

Comment: Is _UpdateTimer static field?

Comment: @dzendras: this is not critical

Comment: Obvious question: why is the event handler marked as `static`?

Comment: well that was easy. The static was a copy paste error from an example taken out of the internet! Thanks you a lot!

Comment: @Viacheslav Smityukh: As you see it was vital :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove static keyword from the event handler declaration!

Comment: From comment by Viacheslav Smityukh.